# Highcharts with Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am in process of upgrading my high charts to version > 7.0. However, when I go through the below URL, it says that I would required Angular version > 10 and high charts version > 7.0 for latest high charts installation.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highcharts

https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts#readme

I currently have Angular version 5. Will it work if I don't upgrade my Angular Version and just upgrade the High Charts version to 7.2.2?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using the official Highcharts wrapper called `highcharts-angular`.

GH: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

There the version required are:

- "@angular/common": ">=6.0.0",
- "@angular/core": ">=6.0.0",
- "highcharts": ">=6.0.0"